# Preventing removal of entity

Tags: symfony, entity

I have an entity (eg Image) which is related to many other entities (eg Product or Category). I would like to know which is the best way to prevent the removal of an entity if a relation exists somewhere else (eg I should not be able to delete an Image if it is related to a product). My thoughts are either searching for relations in a repository class and returning results, or doing 'something' at the preRemove lifecycle event of the entity. Which is the best Symfony2 way for preventing removal of related entities?

Comment: I suppose that best way is to search for releated entities, if any, and then implement your own logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as cascade delete is not set, any directionally entity will prevent delete of the related entity.  If your associations are not birectional, you'll have to query form the backside as well.

To expand upon CJ's answer, you may remove delete links, but you will also have to check the entity in controller as well, because any url hacker can delete an object if its id is known.

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest is you can better of disabled the form delete link when there is a relationship between entities. In that way you can even make the customer understand that there is related entity and he should not remove it before removing the relationship.

You can always check the entity before deleting it and when you actually call certain process in symfony on an entity you actually work on the entire object of that particular entity which gives access to all the values of that entity. So you can check it at that particular point and make conditional statement.

It my personal believe that you should not try to import excess library functions for minor things which can be achieved by you without them. this would make you code easier to understand and even lighter as the prospect for including extra libraries which will most likely have more than what you need